# In R, what is the average frequency (count) of events per ID in Year N?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

**Background**

I've got this `R` dataframe, `d`. It looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"),
                treatment = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0),
                event = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                service_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01",   
                                         "2011-08-21",   
                                         "2011-12-23",   
                                         "2012-02-23",   
                                         "2013-09-14",   
                                         "2013-04-07",   
                                         "2014-10-14",   
                                         "2013-01-01",
                                         "2013-12-12",   
                                         "2014-06-17",
                                         "2015-09-29")), 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's got two people in it (`ID` *a* and *b*) and some information about whether they received a `treatment`, whether they had an `event`, and a `service_date` for when either of those things happens.

**The problem & what I'm looking for**

My goal is to figure out how many `event==1`'s people have on average in their *n*-th year after their first `treatment==1`. Here's the result I'd want, and how I would do it by hand for the first year after treatment:

1. For each `ID`, find the first `service_date` where `treatment` equals `1`. For `ID`=a, that's `2011-08-21`.
2. For that "date of first `treatment`", count forwards 365 days. For `ID`=a, that'd be `2012-08-21`. This gives you an interval for "first year after first `treatment`".
3. Within that interval, count/tally how many times `event==1`. For `ID`=a's first year (so between `2011-08-21` and `2012-08-21`), that's **2** times: once on `2011-12-23` and another on `2012-02-23`.
4. Repeat steps 1, 2, and 3 for the other `ID`'s (in this example it's only b) and get their count. For For `ID`=b', this would only be one event: between `2013-01-01` and one year later on `2014-01-01`, they only have one event, on `2013-12-12`.
5. Sum the counts and divide by number of `ID`'s to get an average. Here, that'd be (2 events + 1 event) / 2 people == **1.5 events, on average, in Year 1 after first treatment**

So in other words it's a calculation that should spit out a single number:

```
> d %>% ... etc etc ... 

# A tibble: 1 x 1
   mean
  <dbl>
1   1.5
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to modify the code to define a different interval after first `treatment`. Like year 2 could be "the time between first `treatment`+365 and first `treatment`+730".

**What I've tried**

I'm messing with some R code to try and do this. Conceptually, my approach consists of the following:

1. First, to `mutate` a new column `year_interval` using the `difftime` function to define the interval in which `R` should be counting events for each `ID`.
2. Next, to `mutate` another column `interval_event_count` that does the actual counting.
3. Finish the operation using `mean`.

This is probably not the only valid approach, of course (it may not even be valid at all ).

So far, I've got this going, but it's giving me an error about `difftime`:

```
d <- d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(service_date) %>%
  mutate(
    year_interval = difftime(min(treatment==1), min(treatment==1)+365, units = "days"),
    interval_event_count = tally(year_interval)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mean(interval_event_count)

Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `year_interval`.
i `year_interval = difftime(min(treatment == 1), min(treatment == 1) + 365, units = "days")`.
x 'origin' must be supplied
i The error occurred in group 1: ID = "a".
Caused by error in `as.POSIXct.numeric()`:
! 'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: `min(treatment == 1)` is minimum of logical vector

Comment: i.e. something like `d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(service_date) %>% mutate(service_date_min = service_date[match(1, treatment)], service_date_max = service_date_min + 365) %>% group_by(service_date_min, .add = TRUE) %>% summarise(n = sum(treatment))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` doing step by step what you provided in your question:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(x = first(service_date[treatment==1]),
         y = first(service_date[treatment==1])+365+1
         ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(z =  ifelse(between(service_date, x, y), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(count = (sum(z[event==1])+1)/2)
```

```
  ID    count
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a       1.5
2 b       1
```

Comment: Will try this out and fiddle with it! Update shortly (I have something in my oven I need to ten do :) )

Comment: Okay so it's giving the right answer, `1.5`, but I'm wondering why it's attached to `a`, and I'm also wondering why it's still showing anything about ID=b in the output. The reason I'm saying this is because the "real" dataset has several thousand `ID`s, and I don't want `R` to crash if it's spitting out a `count` for each `ID`. Your code def. runs on this toy example data; will try it now on my real dataset.

Comment: Hey @TarJae, I figured it out: if you replace the last 3 lines of your answer with: `mutate(z =  ifelse(between(service_date, x+1, y), 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarise(mean = sum(z[event==1])/n_distinct(ID))` , the result is exactly what I was looking for. I replaced `x` with `x+1` in your second `mutate` call, ungrouped by `ID`, and rewrote the `summarise.` If you want to update your answer with this edit, I'll mark yours correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `dplyr` - grouped by 'ID' and 'service_date', get the index of the first occurrence of 1 in 'treatment' with `match`, to get the 'service_date_min', add 365 to return the 'service_date_max', then grouped by 'service_date_min' as well, get the `sum` of 'treatment' (if it is binary, sum returns the count of 1s), then get the `mean` of 'n' once we drop the last group i.e. `service_date_min`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  arrange(ID, service_date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(treatment == 1) > 0) %>%
  mutate(service_date_min = service_date[match(1, treatment)], 
   service_date_max = service_date_min + 365 +1,
    i1 = service_date > service_date_min & 
    service_date < service_date_max & event == 1) %>%
   summarise(n = sum(i1)) %>%
   mutate(n = case_when(n ==1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ sum(n)/n))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  ID        n
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a       1.5
2 b       1
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out in a few minutes.

Comment: Why is service_date_max `2012-08-20` and not `2012-08-20` when we add 365? And note point 5 in the question.

Comment: So this seems to work as you wrote it, but it's not actually giving the mean of `1.5` that I calculated by hand. The output seems to just be giving the (correct) sums of events for each `ID`, which is almost the full way there -- just need to actually average them over the count of `ID`s.

Comment: @logjammin does it have anything to do with `event` column

Comment: Yes I think so: in my thinking, I would need to sum `event` inside the time interval for each ID.

Comment: what is 2 + 1 event

Comment: Well the whole operation would be to (a) sum the events, so 2+1 as you said, and then divide by the total number of `ID` -- which in this case is 2 people (2 `ID`s in other words. (2+1) / 2 == 1.5, which is the answer. (I lay this out in Step 5.)

Comment: @logjammin that formula gives the denominator 3 i.e. `d %>% 
    arrange(ID , service_date) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%     
    mutate(service_date_min = service_date[match(1, treatment)], 
     service_date_max = service_date_min + 365 +1) %>% 
     mutate(i1 = service_date > service_date_min & service_date < service_date_max) %>% summarise(n = sum(event[i1])) %>% mutate(n = sum(n)/n)`

Comment: On that last line `mutate(n = sum(n)/n)` is it possible to replace the denominator with something like `n_distinct(ID)` ??

Comment: @logjammin but that gives both values 1.5

Comment: That's fine actually -- I really only need one line saying 1.5, as that's the correct overall answer (meaning count of events in year 1, summed and averaged over the number of `ID`s).

Comment: @logjammin i made a condition to return 1 if it the value is 1 in the updated solution

Comment: Okay great -- I have to step out for a while so I can't run it right this moment, but I'll try it when I get home and mark the answer correct as soon as I do. The real dataset has thousands of `ID` so it may take a while. Haven't forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just build a small function that does the calculation, and also takes params `s` and `e`

```
f <- function(tx,ev,d,s=0,e=365) {
  tx1 = min(d[tx==1])
  interval = c(tx1+s,tx1+e)
  sum(ev[which(d>=interval[1] & d<=interval[2])])
}
```

Usage:

```
d %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(ev = f(treatment, event, service_date)) %>% 
  summarize(result = mean(ev))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  result
   <dbl>
1    1.5
```

If you want to get some other value, just change the default `s` and `e`, like this:

```
d %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(ev = f(treatment, event, service_date,s=365, e=730)) %>% 
  summarize(result = mean(ev))
```

Even better, make a wrapper function, say `get_events`, like this:

```
get_events <- function(dt,s=0, e=365) {
  group_by(dt,ID) %>%
    summarize(ev = f(treatment, event, service_date, s=s, e=e)) %>% 
    summarize(result = mean(ev))
}
```

and call it like this:

```
get_events(d)
get_events(d,365,730),
get_events(d,e=730)
```

Of course, if you a looking for speed, don't use `group_by()/summarize()`. Instead, set `d` to data.table, and run like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, f(treatment,event,service_date), by=ID][, mean(V1)]
```

Ouptut:

```
[1] 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks for this @langtang. I got TarJae's answer working on my real dataset with a bit of my own modification, but it's relatively slow to run (~15min). Later today I'll try our your version on the data and we'll see if there's maybe a speed improvement. I'd be very grateful if there was. Also: is there any way to add an `sd()` function to the `mean()`, maybe by putting it in that last `summarize` ?

Comment: there will be a speed improvement if you use data.table... see edit.

Comment: Awesome will do. I am a complete novice when it comes to functions, so this is a neat way into them for me. Thanks again!